# Using AWS Elasticache Config Endpoint returns 'READONLY You can't write against a read-only replica'

Tags: redis, next.js, amazon-elasticache

Disclaimer, I'm new to redis and elasticache.
Referencing an answer in this stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71404596/using-endpoints-of-aws-elasticache-for-redis).

I have a basic AWS ElastiCache Redis cluster setup:

- 3 shards, 9 nodes
- encryption at rest

However, when I try to connect to the Configuration endpoint I get `READONLY You can't write against a read-only replica'`.

If I change my connection string to a node endpoint, I connect successfully.

What am I missing here? Why isn't the configuration endpoint navigating me to a non READONLY node?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are copying the primary end point, replica is only read, Since Redis 2.6, replicas support a read-only mode that is enabled by default. This behavior is controlled by the replica-read-only option in the redis.conf file, and can be enabled and disabled at runtime using CONFIG SET.